# Is std::atomic redundant if you have to check for overflow or act conditionally?

Tags: c++, c++11, overflow, atomic, stdatomic

You can safely increment and decrement std::atomic_int for example. But if you need to check for overflow or execute some routine conditinoally based on the value, then a lock is needed anyway. Since you must compare the value and the thread might be swapped off just after the comparison succeeded, another thread modifies, ... bug.

But if you need a lock then you can just use a plain integer instead of atomic. Am I right?

Comment: interestingly there was a second answer (besides the one I accepted) which disappeared and the question got a downvote

Comment: Use the return value of `foo.fetch_add` or `foo++`.  You're right it would be a bug to increment and then do a separate read of the value in most cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can still use a std::atomic even conditionally.

Firstly, overflow behavior for `.fetch_add` is well defined as unsigned or [2's complement wrap-around](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) for atomic types (although possibly not what you want).  Unlike for non-atomic types where integer overflow is still UB.

You're right that `foo++` and then a separate read of `foo` would be a bug, so use `int tmp = foo++;` to use the return value of the atomic RMW operation.

If you absolutely must check for overflow, or otherwise act conditionally, you can use compare-exchange. This lets you read the value, decide whether you want to do work on it and then atomically update the value back if it hasn't changed. And the key part here is the system will tell you if the atomic update *failed*, in which case you can go back to the start and read the new value and make the decision again.

As an example, if we only wanted to set the max value of an atomic integer to 4 (in some kind of refcounting, for instance), we could do:

```
#include <atomic>

static std::atomic<int> refcount = 0;

int val = refcount; // this doesn't need to be in the loop as on failure compare-exchange-strong updates it
while(true)
{
   if(val == 4)
   {
       // there's already 4 refs here, maybe come back later?
       break;
   }

   int toChangeTo = val + 1;
   if(refcount.compare_exchange_weak(val, toChangeTo))
   {
       // we successfully took a ref!
       break;
   }

    // if we fail here, another thread updated the value whilst we were running, just loop back and try again
}
```

Loops like this are often written as `do{...}while(!refcount.compare_exchange_weak(...));`

We use `compare_exchange_weak` instead of `compare_exchange_strong`. This can sometimes spuriously fail and so you need to do it in a loop. However, we have a loop anyway (and in general you always will as you need to handle real failures) and so `compare_exchange_weak` makes a lot of sense here.

On some ISAs, an asm loop is needed to implement `compare_exchange_strong` but not `weak`; on other ISAs like x86, both compile to the same asm.  You're not making anything worse by using `weak` as long as the code to prepare for the next `compare_exchange_weak` attempt is cheap like in this case.

Comment: thanks, btw: for incrementing or checking for overflow this might be better, but in case I expensively calculate the value to update with, then the computation is wasted if someone modified the atomic since then, right?, with a lock I only compute when I surely own it

Comment: The difference between lock free and non lock free programming can make a massive difference. Yes, you can do redundant calculations (although a compare exchange *failure* means another thread *succeded* which means work always gets done). There's a whole lot of information on the topic of lock free programming available - I'd recommended Herb Sutters 'Atomic Weapons' talk [http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2] if you want to understand the real nitty gritty. Infact, any of Herb's recent talks are very good.

Comment: Isn't this the archetypal loop where you use `.compare_exchange_weak` ?

Comment: Overflow of `std::atomic<int>` and other signed atomic integer types *is* well-defined as 2's complement wrap-around.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add  This is different from non-atomic types, probably because it would make it impossible to write some algorithms safely since you can't check for and avoid overflow with operations like `fetch_add`.